# Nativescript-Vue How to make Transparency to Page component who will not affect the childs

Tags: css, xml, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Hi i hope you are well.

I have an issue and i couldn't fix it i want to attach a `background-image` property from url and want to add an opacity with color on it who will not affect the childs.

Actually everything take the opacity if someone can help me it will be great !

Thank you by advance

Here is my sample of code:

```
<template>
    <Page class="ns-light page">
        <ActionBar :title="`${actionBarName}`"/>
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5%">
            <Label text="Tap to play the music" style="font-weight: bold"/>

            <Image :src="src" @tap="playSound" width="300" style="margin-top: 5%"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </Page>
</template>

<style scoped>
    ActionBar {
        background-color: #53ba82;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .page {
        background: url('~/assets/images/cards/background.png') no-repeat center #53ba82;
        background-size: cover;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please confirm: you have a `background-image` set on `<Page>` and you want to place an semi-transparent overlay above the `background-image` but the content should be rendered above the overlay. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly actually i have a `background: url` but i want only apply the opacity on it

Comment: You can't apply opacity on the `background-image` layer without affecting the contents. The `opacity` applies to everything rendered by that element. You have two options: a) you modify the image itself and make it semi-transparent. b) instead of using `background-image` you use a pseudo (`:before` or `:after`), you position it absolutely to cover the entire element and you give every single child element a `z-index` of 1, while giving the pseudo a z-index of 0. If you need it, I can provide an example.

Comment: For b) solution you can obviously play with the pseudo element's `opacity` on the fly and you place the `background-image` on it, instead of the parent element. The whole point is to place the `background-image` on a different element, so that changing its opacity doesn't affect anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to: [Tao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/tao) who took the time to answer me

After trying a lot of things i read the documentation and found out how to do it !

Problematic: "i want an image as a background and a transparent color above the image."

I will explain myself, so i tried to apply css `background-image` and adding the opacity to it.

1. The `opacity`

The `opacity` is going to modify all of the elements inside your chosen element.

When i used `opacity` in `Page` it even changed the opacity of the image and that was not what i was looking for ...

1. The `alpha` (`rgba`)

And then i thought there is `alpha = rgba()` and you can achieve the transparency of the specific element so = "a color transparent above the image."

So what I did was very simple, I had to see if I could define an rgba class on one of the child elements and i chose: `GridLayout` (the Layout Container).

So i added a `background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1)` and then i had the color with transparency

And i let the `background-image` on `Page` component and that did the trick ! :D

I will put the code of it with the second code over here:

```
  <template>
    <Page class="ns-light page">
        <ActionBar title="Audio Mémo Manjak - Accueil"/>
        <GridLayout width="100%" height="100%" columns="*,*,*,*,*"  rows="auto,auto,auto,auto,auto" class="layout">
            <StackLayout v-for="(card, index) of cards" :key="index" :col="`${ index % 5 }`" :row="`${ index / 5 }`">
                <Image :src="card.src" style="margin: 30px 15px;" @tap="onTappedFun(card)"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
<style>
    ActionBar {
        background-color: #53ba82;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .page {
        background-image: url("~/assets/images/cards/background.png");
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .layout {
        background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
        padding-top: 100%;
    }
</style>
```